Paired vs 2-sample t-test
I’m comfortable with the general decision and underlying assumptions between paired and 2-sample t-tests.
Suppose I wish to collect data on, for example, how long it takes my oven to heat up to 200 degrees vs how long it takes for my neighbour’s oven to do the same, with a view to seeing which is quicker.
I decide I can only reasonably do this once per day, and so on ten randomly chosen days of the year I time how long my oven takes, and for the sake of ease do the same for my neighbour’s oven on the same day. I end up with ten days of measurements for my oven, and ten for my neighbour.
My understanding is that the use of a paired t-test assumes each pair is not independent - i.e. there is dependence between what my oven did on day 3 and what theirs did on day 3. Perhaps due to the temperature that day, or whatever.
If I was to suppose that outside temperature doesn’t really matter, since we both heat our homes to 20 degrees anyway every day, and thus my day 3 measurement is independent from theirs, would a two-sample t-test instead be the appropriate choice? Since the day-measured pairing was only one of convenience, rather than because pairs of measurements are correlated?
My feeling is to go with paired, since I am not confident in any assumption that measurements are independent (we actually perhaps allow external temperatures to dictate our homes’ temperatures). But in order to do this I am implicitly assuming that pairs (i.e my day 3 and their day 3) are correlated?
Many thanks!

The short answer is that in both cases, use a paired test statistic, even if you have controlled for all known confounders, so long as the observations are truly paired.
This would not be the case if, for instance, you wished to perform individual hypothesis tests on the behavior of each oven; e.g., you wish to test whether your oven takes more than $15$ minutes to reach temperature.  But because your research question is only interested in which oven is faster, then a paired test statistic is justified whenever the selection of when each oven is operated is related.  What I mean by this is that even if you were to randomize the operation days such that your neighbor's oven is tested on the next day or even next week after the random days when you operate your own oven (so for instance, if you picked days $17$, $39$, $57$, $81$, $105$, $133$, $187$, $215$, $310$, $354$ to operate your oven, and you chose to operate your neighbor's oven on the next day after each of these days), the observations are still paired.  The caveat here is in the interpretation of the test conclusions, because such a delay potentially introduces a confounding factor.  But it does not invalidate the choice to use a paired test--indeed, the two-sample test would also be confounded in the same way, because this is a shortcoming in the experimental design.
Choosing to use a two-sample test is not statistically wrong, and it can lead to meaningful inferences, but the disadvantage is that it will tend to be more conservative with respect to the estimated variance of the difference between the two ovens' preheat times; thus, while the Type I error remains controlled, the two-sample test will have less power to detect whether one oven is faster than the other.
A situation in which you cannot use a paired test is, of course, when the operation times of each oven are selected independently at random, even when the same number of trials are performed on each.  Another way to look at it is that whenever the assumptions about the variance in the paired difference between oven times are violated, you cannot use the paired test.

Thanks for that - I think that all makes sense, except that my understanding/assumption had been that if I were truly to assert/know that there was independence within pairs then a two-sample test would instead be preferred due to the increased degrees of freedom increasing the power of the test. I guess the question then is, would I be irrational to persist with a paired test at the same time as asserting that measurements within each pair are independent?

@TenSilentMiles See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paired_difference_test#Power_of_the_paired_Z-test for more information.

That is helpful especially in giving a condition such that the power of the paired test exceeds that of an independent samples test. But I’m not sure whether I can interpret that a two-sample independent test is actually preferable to a paired test when the pairwise data is independent such that their covariance is zero.

@TenSilentMiles The choice of test statistic is not solely motivated by power.  First and foremost, it is selected on the basis of the design of the experiment and the underlying parametric model that the data are assumed to follow.  Then, under such assumptions, we choose an appropriate testing procedure that preferably maximizes the power while controlling Type I error.  When the data are paired because you collected it that way, you use a paired test statistic, even if there is negative covariance, because the paired samples are not independent and you must account for this.
